# Strange Left-SHIFT and Left-ALT behavior of Windows XP (some type of reassignment)

Tags: windows-xp

I acquired a PC from someone. They don't know what happened either. Basically when I'm in firefox, and anytime I press the Left-SHIFT, then the Bookmarks bar pops out.

Anytime I press the Left-ALT, such as using Alt-Tab to switch programs, then VLC Media player opens up. If I press ALT 5 times fast, I get 5 instances of VLC. There must be some type of Key-assignment or hotkey thing going but I can't figure out where that might be.

Any ideas? Thanks.

ps. I already looked in Control panel > accessibility, and keyboard settings, doesnt seem to have any hotkey reassignment in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the keyboard come with the machine? Does the same thing happen with a different keyboard?

Comment: good question. will check. It is a wireless keyboard so maybe some type of interference...

Comment: Was it a keyboard issue, Tim?